# Bootstrap 3 Div Ordering Desktop vs Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hopefully this image explains exactly what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: Twitter Bootstrap 3 desktop vs mobile div ordering]

Since the blue block represents a simple list, I think it may be easier to just output the block twice, and apply a "desktop-only" and "mobile-only" class, then use that class to dictate visibility, but I was curious to know if the above is possible with pure HTML/CSS out of box for Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">First</div>
    <div class="col-md-8" id="big">Big</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Second</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    #big {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8r4g20cr/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it possible but from your layout you need something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="marron"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

When you the screen resized, the div in rows will be stacked up orderly. I don't think I can reorder it for mobile devices. Stay tune for other opinions.